# Can't get object values from Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

In Angular 5 + Firebase (AngularFire) project i have service `Current`, where i get current user data from Firebase RDB:

```
  export class CurrentService {

  public current;

  constructor(
    private authFb: AngularFireAuth,
    private db: AngularFireDatabase
  ) {
    this.isLoggedIn().pipe(
      tap(user => {
        if (user) {
          this.current = this.db.object(`users/${user.uid}`)
          .valueChanges()
        } else {
          this.current = null;
          console.log("no")
        }
      })
    )
    .subscribe()
  }

  isLoggedIn() {
    return this.authFb.authState.pipe(first())
  }
}
```

And  in view i want bind `current` values:

```
{{ currService.current?.username }}
```

But its return `null`. What is strange, becouse when i bind `{{ (currService.current | async) | json }}` its return full object with fields and values in json format. What i did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `async` pipe as well:

```
{{ (currService.current | async)?.username }}
```